# Images not working on website?

Tags: html, css

Hi everyone please bear with me if there is a simple reason for this as this is the first site i have designed and hosted, and its taken long enough just to sort out how to get it uploaded and the domain name pointing to it correctly.

The issue is I designed my website in dream weaver CS5. I created a separate folder to store all images associated with the site. unfortunately after uploading the site and visiting it the images are all missing and i am not sure why? The site is brettmoney.com or brett money.co.uk.

Secondly this isn't a major issue and i still need to play around with it and could be easy to fix but my nav bar at the top shifts onto 2 lines in IE but is correct on chrome.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is due to the path problem which you have specified like Images instead of images.So use images/logo.png. And secondly your top navigation is breaking in IE browser due to spacing. You have to decrease the padding which you have given in  `.NavBar ul li {
margin: 0px;
**padding: 0px 16px;**
list-style: none;
display: inline;`

Comment: I have no idea how or why i may have changed the images folder yet it still worked when hitting the F12 key but any way that sorted. thank you for advising on the nav bar was just playing around with those and seemed to sort it. Is there a way of somehow spacing them out equally? not a problem if not just thought something like that could neaten up the code. Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

your image paths are case sensitive, I changed one from `Images/Next_Event_UK_north_hants.png` to `images/Next_Event_UK_north_hants.png` and it appeared

Answer (score 1):

`Images/Logo.png` should be `images/logo.png`

Case matters for *nix based environments.

Answer (score 0):

Have you placed your Images folder inside your public_html folder? As this may be the cause as I get a 404 error when looking for that folder.

**Edit:** From the looks of it you need to make sure you are using the correct case as the folder images exists but not Images